# Keras bidirectional LSTM: initial_state` was passed that is not compatible with `cell.state_size

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm attempting to build a stacked bidirectional LSTM seq2seq model in Keras, however I am running into an issue when passing the output states of the encoder to the input states of the decoder. It looks like that should be possible based on this [pull request](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/9248). Ultimately I want to keep the `encoder_output` vector for additional downstream tasks.

The error message:

```
ValueError: An `initial_state` was passed that is not compatible with `cell.state_size`. Received `state_spec`=[InputSpec(shape=(None, 100), ndim=2)]; however `cell.state_size` is (100, 100)
```

My model:

```
MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 50
EMBEDDING_DIM = 250
latent_size_1 = 100
latent_size_2 = 50
latent_size_3 = 250

embedding_layer = Embedding(num_words,
                            EMBEDDING_DIM,
                            embeddings_initializer=Constant(embedding_matrix),
                            input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
                            trainable=False,
                            mask_zero=True)

encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,), name="encoder_input")
encoder_emb = embedding_layer(encoder_inputs)
encoder_lstm_1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(latent_size_1, return_sequences=True),                                                         
                               merge_mode="concat",
                               name="encoder_lstm_1")(encoder_emb)
encoder_outputs, forward_h, forward_c, backward_h, backward_c = Bidirectional(LSTM(latent_size_2, return_state=True), 
                               merge_mode="concat"
                               name="encoder_lstm_2")(encoder_lstm_1)
state_h = Concatenate()([forward_h, backward_h])
state_c = Concatenate()([forward_c, backward_c])
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,), name="decoder_input")
decoder_emb = embedding_layer(decoder_inputs)
decoder_lstm_1 =  Bidirectional(LSTM(latent_size_1, return_sequences=True), 
                                merge_mode="concat", 
                                name="decoder_lstm_1")(decoder_emb, initial_state=encoder_states)
decoder_lstm_2 =  Bidirectional(LSTM(latent_size_3, return_sequences=True), 
                                merge_mode="concat",
                                name="decoder_lstm_2")(decoder_lstm_1)
decoder_outputs = Dense(num_words, activation='softmax', name="Dense_layer")(decoder_lstm_2)

seq2seq_Model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)
```

Any help/advice/direction is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you are getting the forward and backward states separately, shouldn't you pass them also separately instead of concatenating?

Comment: @DanielMöller, I also tried passing them as a list  `encoder_states = [forward_h, forward_c, backward_h, backward_c]`, but got the following error ```An `initial_state` was passed that is not compatible with `cell.state_size`. Received `state_spec`=[InputSpec(shape=(None, 50), ndim=2), InputSpec(shape=(None, 50), ndim=2)]; however `cell.state_size` is (100, 100)```

Comment: Notice that "mode sum" brings an output that is half the size of "mode concat". One of the states is the last output.

Comment: Thanks for catching that discrepancy (fixed in the question), however changing all of the merge_modes to `concat` and concatenating the forwards/backwards cell states, or adding the cell states and keeping `merge_mode='sum'` doesn't change the error message.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two issues with your code,

1. as @Daniel pointed out, you should not concatenate the states in the `encoder_states` (rather have `encoder_states = [forward_h, forward_c, backward_h, backward_c]`)
2. The state returned by your encoder is of size `latent_size_2` (not `latent_size_1`). So if you want that as your decoder initial state, your decoder should be `latent_size_2`.

You can find the code with these corrections below.

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding, Input, Bidirectional, LSTM, Dense, Concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.initializers import Constant
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 50
EMBEDDING_DIM = 250
latent_size_1 = 100
latent_size_2 = 50
latent_size_3 = 250
num_words = 5000
embedding_layer = Embedding(num_words,
                            EMBEDDING_DIM,
                            embeddings_initializer=Constant(1.0),
                            input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
                            trainable=False,
                            mask_zero=True)

encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,), name="encoder_input")
encoder_emb = embedding_layer(encoder_inputs)
encoder_lstm_1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(latent_size_1, return_sequences=True),                                                         
                               merge_mode="concat",
                               name="encoder_lstm_1")(encoder_emb)
encoder_outputs, forward_h, forward_c, backward_h, backward_c = Bidirectional(LSTM(latent_size_2, return_state=True), 
                               merge_mode="concat", name="encoder_lstm_2")(encoder_lstm_1)
encoder_states = [forward_h, forward_c, backward_h, backward_c]

decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,), name="decoder_input")
decoder_emb = embedding_layer(decoder_inputs)
decoder_lstm_1 =  Bidirectional(
    LSTM(latent_size_2, return_sequences=True), 
    merge_mode="concat", name="decoder_lstm_1")(decoder_emb, initial_state=encoder_states)
decoder_lstm_2 =  Bidirectional(LSTM(latent_size_3, return_sequences=True), 
                                merge_mode="concat",
                                name="decoder_lstm_2")(decoder_lstm_1)
decoder_outputs = Dense(num_words, activation='softmax', name="Dense_layer")(decoder_lstm_2)

seq2seq_Model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)
```

Comment: I was looking for a solution to the exact same question. Thank you so much! @thusvh89